# Can peewee drop a database

Tags: python, peewee

I am working on a function within a project that could drop staging databases. I already use peewee throughout the project so it would make things easier to not have use pymysql . Is it possible? I've seen it i believe for dropping tables but not a db.

Just double checking

I did see  a ticket in github from 2014 regarding this issue but wanted to see if there was any new info on this as a possibility.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to just try it than posting here?

Comment: I wouldn't be posting here if i haven't been trying different things.  I am newer to peewee and has looked over peewee docs, stack overflow and github. i'm not sure what command that would even be ,but i've been trying as a result i posted here. I wanted to make sure i wasn't missing something and verify that it doesn't work before trying new tech i have less experience with. I'm newer to stack overflow is the way i asked question not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Peewee has no provisions for either creating or deleting databases, no will it ever be likely to support that. Check your db vendor for the appropriate methods for doing this.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! super appreciate your response